# Debug python side attaching to a c++ local process that call python scripts

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

is there a good way to debug python side attaching to a native process that call python scripts?
I tried using Visual Studio but it didn't work, I saw under attach process window that it is a X64/Python process but if I try to attach to it, then it doesn't ask any python symbols and it doesn't stop at python breakpoints.

Any help?

Thank you